# Output of hypothesis testing using r

Tags: r, chi-squared

My code snippet for the chi square test results.

```
for (i in 8:ncol(aputanalysis))
{
  tmp <- chisq.test(table(aputanalysis[, i], aputanalysis[, 7]))
  print(chisq.test(table(aputanalysis[, i], aputanalysis[, 7])))
}
```

The results are:

```
[1] 9.334636e-18

Pearson's Chi-squared test
data:  table(aputanalysis[, i], aputanalysis[, 7])
X-squared = 118.8, df = 16, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I want to display the column names along with the other information.

How do I get the column names along with p value, df and X-squared?

Comment: could you please add an example data set? Something small to reproduce the error? Also, showing what is exactly is expected output would help. Regardless, if you look into the function's help `chisq.test` it will most likely tell you want you need. For instance, the pvalue can be accessed with `tmp$p.value`. `str(tmp)` will also be of value.

Comment: you test column `i` and column 7 of your data aputanalysis. Now you want to know for every `i ` the corresponding name of the actual column in your data frame?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to print the column names of the columns you use you can add the following before your existing print() statement:

```
print(paste("Now testing", colnames(aputanalysis[i]), "and",  colnames(aputanalysis[7])))
```

Note that the used data can be printed by using

```
tmp$data.name
```

This will print `table(aputanalysis[, i], aputanalysis[, 7])`

This information, however, can be overwritten by using something like this

```
tmp$data.name <- paste("Test for", colnames(aputanalysis[i]), "and",  colnames(aputanalysis[7]))
```